# running cloud init script in gce

Tags: google-compute-engine, cloud-init

Is it possible to provide cloud-init script for VM instance on ubuntu in GCE?
i.e. to run something like

```
gcloud compute instances create my1 --image ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20150316 --metadata-from-file startup-script=my.cloudconfig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2022, Ubuntu images in GCE comes with `cloud-init`. Setting a `user-data` instance metadata lets `cloud-init` see and interpret it.

// for example the `projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-2204-jammy-v20220810` OS image.

However I think the command OP demonstrated is `startup-script`, which is a bash script executed by some GCE-specific service like `google-startup-script`, and have little to do with `cloud-init`.

(Not every distribution has preinstalled `cloud-init`. Debian does not.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to partially work. Writing files seems to be fine but it seems to be failing on any runcmd. I think if you can get away w/ it do this:

In the VM metadata create a key called user-data with your entire cloud config script in it as text. That will be picked up by the VM as it comes up.

Then in startup-script paste all your commands you'd put in runcmd.

All this may have ordering issues for you of course, but I don't any other way to do it.